# How do I write a program to show the truth table for the NAND gate in python 2.7.15

Tags: python-2.7, truthtable

How do I write a program to show the truth table for the NAND gate

Answer (score 0):

`output = not all(list(inputs))`

Prettify it all you want.

Comment: for loops or import __future__ print_function for print(args, sep=' fancy delimiter ')